# Vuejs binding Progress Circle with text active class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this app.
[image]

I'm tryna make when progress %20 bottom section text number 1 (Your answers are being analyzed)

opacity = 0.4; --> opacity = 1; I mean I guess active class but how to bind with progress bar ı dont know.

Progress percent %40 text number 2

Progress percent %60 text number 3

Progress percent stops %75 (and there will be popup, this section my part)

When pop-up closed Progress bar keep going from 75 to 100

I'm using this plugin for progress circle: https://github.com/setaman/vue-ellipse-progress

```
<template>
    <div>
        
        <section class="AboutSection d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-start text-center pt-5">

            <div>
                <router-link to="/eighthPage" class="BackBtn"> <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/back.png"/></router-link>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid logoHeader">
                <h1>Vue-VPN</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="AboutText container-fluid ">

                <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center text-center ">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h2 class="fw-bolder my-5">Thanks! Your plan is being prepared</h2>
                        <p class="py-3" style="color: #1488CC;">Please wait a moment...</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
                        

<!-- PROGRESS CIRCLE -->
                        <ve-progress class="progressCircle position-relative"   :progress="75"    />
<!-- END PROGRESS CIRCLE -->

<!-- TEXT SECTION-->
                        <ul class="p-0 m-0 mt-3">
                            <li class="my-3 d-flex justify-content-start progressText">
                                <i class="fas fa-check me-2 pt-1" style="color: limegreen;"></i>
                                <p>Your answers are being analyzed. </p>    
                            </li>

                            <li class="my-3 d-flex justify-content-start progressText">
                                <i class="fas fa-check me-2 pt-1" style="color: limegreen;"></i>
                                <p>Account setup in progress. </p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="my-3 d-flex justify-content-start progressText">
                                <i class="fas fa-check me-2 pt-1" style="color: limegreen;"></i>
                                <p>Server location setup is in progress. </p>
                            </li>

                            <li class="my-3 d-flex justify-content-start progressText">
                                <i class="fas fa-check me-2 pt-1" style="color: limegreen;"></i>
                                <p>Your account is being created. </p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
<!-- END TEXT SECTION-->

                    </div>

                    <h1>IN PROGRESS</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
// import percentCounter from '../components/percentCounter.vue'
// import Progress from '../components/progress2.vue'
    export default {
        el: '#app',
        components: { 
            // percentCounter ,
            // Progress
        },
        methods:{
            
        }
    }
</script>

<style  scoped>
.progressCircle{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.progressCircle::before{
    content: '%';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.progressText{
    opacity: .4;
    color: #111;
}
</style>
```

if you have an idea it could be anything please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Track your percent in a variable. Then compare if the `percent` passes text line's percent.

Checkout code snippet below.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ol>
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index">
        <label :class="{ passed: percent >= todo.percent }">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        { text: "Learn JavaScript", percent: 20 },
        { text: "Learn Vue", percent: 40 },
        { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", percent: 60 },
      ],
      percent: 10,
      interval: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increasePercent: function() {
      this.percent += 10
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.increasePercent, 500)
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
li {
  margin: 8px 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
  label {
    opacity: 0.4;
    &.passed {
      opacity: 1;
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnhuyduy/e0up76y9/27/)

Comment: dude this is okey but I'm actually asking for `:progress="75(value)"` bind with text progress circle percent == 20 then text-1 css line-through. I'm asking how to get `:progress= value `